# Flask session.logged_in not working

Tags: python, if-statement, flask

Using Flask session I am testing whether the user is logged in using 
`{%if session.logged_in%}` display a logout button, and `{%else%}` to display login and register buttons. I am following this tutorial [Python Flask From Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QEMtSUxtUDY&t=4s) and using the Flask documentation on templates as a [guide](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/templates/) .

The author of the tutorial is using Bootstrap and I am using Semantic-UI but up until now I have not run in to any issues, I am receiving the error and success messages as described in the tutorial.

The only issue I'm having is my logout button is not displaying when the user is logged in; which is explained at approx. 20:45 in the tutorial.

My code for _navbar.html:

```
 <div class="ui large menu">
  <div class="ui container">
    <a href="/" class="item">Home</a>
    <a href="/about" class="item">About</a>
    <a href="/articles" class="item">Articles</a>

    <div class="right menu">
        {% if session.logged_in %}
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/logout" class="ui button">Logout</a>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/login" class="ui button">Login</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <a href="/register" class="ui primary button">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{% if session.logged_in %}
```

try using

```
{% if session['logged in'] == True %}
```